# Replicating Arduino's serial communication on atmega328p

Tags: arduino, atmega, serial-communication

I have a simple circuit, with an ESP8266 and an Arduino Nano, communicated via Serial.

To test this communication, I send a simple "TURN ON" string and the Arduino should turn on a LED.

This is the Arduino code:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {

  if(Serial.available() > 0) 
  {
    String command = "";
    while(Serial.available())
    {
      command += (char)Serial.read();
      delay(1);
      if (command == "T"){
        while(Serial.available())
        {
          command += (char)Serial.read();
          delay(1);
        }
      }else{
        command = "";
      }
    }

    if(command == "TURN ON") {
      digitalWrite(3, HIGH);  
    }

    if(command == "TURN OFF") {
      digitalWrite(3, LOW);
    }
  }

  delay(500);
}
```

This works fine.

Now, I would like to replace the Arduino with an Atmega328p.

I have the basic circuit:
[image]

Plus the led, and the TX and RX pins connected to the ESP8266.

If I upload the same code to the Atmega328p, it doesn't work, so I guess I'm missing something very important (like UART configuration or something) but I don't know what that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case that someone arrives here with a similar issue:

**Yes, it should work as I intended.**

I was using a damaged breadboard! (you can't receive a message if the pins are not connected ... )

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you have used an external programmer with the Atmega328p, and it is a fresh Atmega328p.

If my assumptions are right, then the fuse bits within your Atmega328p are set to use the internal 1MHz clock, and that is causing the problem.

What you can do to fix this:
Connect the programmer to the Atmega328p
Go to tools>boards, select Arduino Uno in the Boards.
Go to tools>programmer select the programmer you are using.
Go to tools and select Burn bootloader.

You can then upload your code to the Atmega328p, it should start working the way you expect it to.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Nitro, actually I've done that already but it still isn't working.
You are right, it's a fresh Atmega328p with an external programmer.
Are you saying that the exact same code should work as well?

Comment: I have done this before, that's why I know it should work. If your code works with an Arduino, then the same code will work with an Atmega328p, as long as the fuse bits are correct.

Comment: Thanks, that's refreshing. The fuses configuration is on the boards.txt file right? I have one custom configuration for the Atmega328p standalone, but maybe something is missing, can you please share the configuration that worked for you?

Comment: The fuse configuration is done when you do a burn bootloader. You don't have to change the boards file for it.

I suggest using the Arduino Uno Board.

Just make sure that you are using the same board while uploading the bootloader and while uploading the code.

If you have modified the Board files and don't remember the original fuse bits, I suggest reinstalling the Arduino IDE

Comment: Also the Board files available with the Arduino IDE define the F_CPU along with the fuse bits to be used. IF you are planning on changing the fuse bits via the Boards.txt file, ensure that you correctly change the F_CPU as well.

I have used the following link for almost 6 years to calculate the right fuse bit for the right CPU frequency, for the right IC.

Be careful though. A wrong fuse bit configuration can brick your ic.

Comment: Thanks. I tried using the UNO configuration and it didn't work. I'll check that link but the UNO settings on boards.txt wasn't modified.

Comment: What programmer are you using? and how have you connected the Atmega328p to your computer for serial communication?
Did you do a loopback test on the hardware you are using to communicate with the atmega328p?

Comment: I'm using an arduino Nano as an ISP. I'm not connecting the Atmega328p to the computer, the communication is between the Atmega328p (or the Arduino Nano in the test that worked) and an ESP8266

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the Serial API is very sensitive to the timing of the bytes.  Depending on the timing of the bytes that are received, you might just go back to the top of your loop and set `command` to the empty string, meaning your program forgets about the bytes it saw earlier.  You were lucky that this code worked on one processor, and it's not surprising that it fails on another.

How about you limit yourself to one-byte commands for now?  'T' could turn on the LED and 'S' could turn it off.  To implement multi-byte commands, you will probably need a small state machine, and you will need to feed it bytes from the UART one at a time, in a way that doesn't depend on the timing.

Comment: I get your point, but I think the issue is not that (yet). I added a simple `if (Serial.available() > 0 ) { digitalWrite(2, HIGH); }` but pin 2 isn't being set to HIGH, so there is no serial message received whatsoever.

Comment: "No serial message whatsoever" looks like wrong timing (clock fuses)
Did you ever get a blink sketch running on your standalone atmega328 ?

Comment: Yes, in fact, I've added a led blinking in the same sketch and it is blinking.